# Resizing a cell which contains a tableview with dynamic content in it

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Tableview inside a Table View cell. 
The Tableview has a accordian view that can expand or collapse.
How to resize the cell to the tableview height which changes dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a delegate.

Create a protocol that your outer table view controller conforms to:

```
func cellHeightChanged(newHeight: CGFloat) {
  self.cellHeight = newHeight
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Then give the inner table view a reference to the outer controller and call this method whenever the height changes.